# How to set setOnItemClickListener to listview?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I try to setOnItemClickListener for customized listview.I set the adapter as

```
final ListView searchlist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.prodlist);
String[] from = new String[] {"rowid", "col_1", "col_2","col_3"};
int[] to = new int[] { R.id.checkBox1, R.id.editText1, R.id.editText2, R.id.editText3}; 

 //added data to the components using for loop.

 SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, fillMaps, R.layout.prod_view,from, to);
 list.setAdapter(adapter); 
      list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
            {
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position, long id)
                    {
                    Toast.makeText(Prod.this,"" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
                    }
          });
```

But when i click the checkbox in the listview,it not display the toast message.How can I get the position when the checkbox is checked in the listview?

Comment: Toast message will display when you click inside the listview items. As you have added the checkbox then you have to manage the checkbox events inside the adapter. Please check the events inside the adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Implement checkBox click event then. Why are you implemented ListView click event. Using setTag() and getTag(), get your checkBox id proper and then implement checkBox click event.

Comment: I want to delete all the item in a selected listview.For that only i implemented in listview.

Comment: ya but you can do it using on checkbox listener also. list.remove(position) when you click on checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following attribute to the layout of your item:

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

Otherwise the checkbox inside the item will handle the event. This will allow you to handle the event in the listview.

E.g. if your item's layout starts with

```
<RelativeLayout        
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" >

... the rest of the item

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,  use `setOnCheckedChangeListener`

```
   mHolder.mcheckbox
                    .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onCheckedChanged(
                                CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                //Do your stuff here
                        }
                    });
```